# how to remove underline for anchor link in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have anchor tag in jquery as

```
success: function(result) {
   $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href="#"><font color=black><strong>' + result.name+ '</font></a></td></tr>');
```

to remove the underline i have added style property ,but it is not removing the underline.How can i remove the underline for anchor tag?

thanks,
michaled

Comment: Can you post CSS definition for remove class?

Comment: actually storng is taking style underline property i have added in strong STYLE="text-decoration:none", solved my issue thnx

Answer (score 2):

Try this with important, in case any other style rule is overriding the inline style with important.

```
$('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a style="text-decoration:none !important;" href="#"><font color=black><strong>' + result.name+ '</font></a></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try properly closing your anchor, font, and strong tags:

```
success: function(result) {
    $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a STYLE="text-decoration:none"><font color="black"><strong>' + result.FileName + '</strong></font></a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: al tags are closed properly i have edited my code sry for the typo error

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close the anchor tag near to the font tag

try this i am not sure it's correct or not

```
$('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a STYLE="text-decoration:none"><font color=black><strong>' + result.FileName + '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
```

or try this

```
$('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a><font color=black><strong>' + result.FileName + '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
$('#MyGrid tbody tr td a').css("text-decoration","none");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration : none">HTML Hyperlink without Underline using inline style</a>
```

This worked for me.

Or else you can try with CSS style:

```
<html> <head> 
<title>HTML Hyperlink No Underline</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
a {font-family : Arial; Font-size : 12px; text-decoration : none} 
a:link {color : #ff0000} 
a:visited {color : #00ff00} 
a:active {color : #666666} 
a:hover {color : #0000ff} 
</style> 
</head>
```